# UIBarButtonItem tintColor & style doesn't work on iPhone but OK on iPad

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

In my app I have a `UIToolbar` created on xcode stoaryboard, on the toolbar there is a `UIBarButtonItem`, a toggle button. When the button status changes, following functions are called to make visual changes on the button:

```
button.tintColor = buttonDown ? colourDown : colourUp;
button.style = buttonDown ? UIBarButtonItemStyleDone : UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
```

it works well on iPad, iPad mini; but on iPhone iPod, there is no visual changes on the button. iOS version is not a matter, tested on iOS 7 & 8, the same result. All UI components are created on StoryBoard. I also tried to change button title, width, none of them works. Appreciate any solutions or suggestions.

Comment: Are using one or two storyboards?

Comment: Not quite sure what "two storyboards" means. One storyboard, one view.

Comment: One for iPhone and one for iPad or one storyboard for both

Comment: OK understood. One storyboard for iphone the other for ipad. The classes of toolbar and buttons-on-the-bar are identical in two storyboards.

Comment: Thank you Moxy for letting me pay attention to the differences between iPhone storyboard and iPad storyboard. I am fixing bugs of others' code. Finally I found the problem, on iPhone storyboard, the button's outlet reference was not set, so there is no reference set for variable "button".